# remote_attr retorna um IP incompleto, como resolver?

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um sistema de login, e na hora de buscar o ip com `$_SERVER['remote_addr']` o ip vem assim :  `" ::1 "`

Alguém sabe me explicar o porque? Será a minha maquina?

Comment: ::1 é o IPv6 equivalente ao IPv4 127.0.0.1. Você pode obter o resultado esperado alterando no httpd.conf do apache a linha: Listen 80 para Listen 127.0.0.1:80 e logo após reiniciar o apache.

Comment: Agora meu wamp não quer iniciar

Comment: Editei a linha errada, agora deu certo! Obrigado amigo